# Typescript: unit tests and dependencies

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am having a hard time setting unit tests for my pet project in Typescript.

Consider following directory structure

```
/src
   /test
      unittest.ts
      unittest.html
    main.ts
```

`main.ts`:

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {
    }
}
export { Point };
```

`unittest.ts`

```
import Point from "../main";

function basicTest() {
   let Point = new Point(10, 15);
   // ... 
}

basicTest();
```

`unittest.html`

```
<html>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="unittest.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After compile this code `tsc src/test/unittest.ts && open src/test/unittests.html`

I see following error
`ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I have tried to add requirejs to unittest.html, but it lead to some obscure error. Also I tried to use `--module system` and `--module amd` during compilation, but didn't succeed).

Did I miss some dependency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way to resolve dependencies in this case is using 
`browserify` and it's plugin `tsify`:

```
browserify src/test/unittest.ts -p [ tsify --debug ] > src/test/unittest.js
```

Answer (score 2):

That import line in your test will compile down to something like...

```
var foo_1 = require("./foo");
```

The require statement needs to be configured.  Javascript doesn't come with module loading support out of the box.  There are several different ways that can be done.  They are all different approaches on "how do I find the module asked for and load it in."  I'll let you do some research on the various module resolution mechanisms in Javascript but there are four main approaches:

- CommonJS (legacy node/backend mechanism)
- AMD (legacy browser/frontend mechanism)
- global (oldest browser approach, doesn't use `require`, you just reference the dependent library in your HTML with a `<script>` tag)
- ES2015 (newer mechanism meant to unify all of these approaches).

If this is a newer project you probably want a tool that supports ES2015 style.  RequireJS is a tool for supporting AMD module loading.  You might want to look into Webpack or SystemJS which are popular approaches.  I work mostly with SystemJS.  You don't usually want to configure SystemJS by hand, I would recommend using `jspm` which does that.  You can find a getting started guide [here](http://jspm.io/docs/getting-started.html).

If you would rather look at Webpack you can get started [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/).

Comment: What's the easiest approach? I don't plan to have a lot of unit tests, so I don't want to spend too much time setting them up.

Comment: This is less about unit tests and more about using your application at all.  Will you main.ts ever import any other libraries?  If so, you will need to figure something out.  I haven't ever used webpack so I can't speak to that.  Getting started with jspm doesn't take too long, and once you've gotten started, it is pretty seamless to rebuild and relaunch.

Comment: Thank you! I don't plan to use any external libraries (I use `npm` to keep things organized) and want to keep my project as clean and minimal as possible. I just need some machinery to keep my project modular.

Comment: Aren't npm libraries external libraries?

Comment: I use `npm` just for common actions (`build`, `test` and so on) and `typescript`. Project's current incarnation does not require any external libraries.